# NotSupportedException: Encoding 874 data could not be found. Make sure you have correct international codeset assembly installed and enabled

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write code with a class SqlConnection. I run on UNITY_EDITOR there is no problem, but when I try to build .apk file and try to run. It shows the problem follows in the picture. I try to debug it out one by one. Found that there is a problem with the `connection.Open();` method.

**Code sample:**

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=server01;Initial Catalog=StoreDB;User ID=sa;Password=sapassword;";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
sqlCommand.Connection = connection;
sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT username FROM dbo.Profile_Users";
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
DataTable profile_Username = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(profile_Username);
```

**Problem:** NotSupportedException: Encoding 874 data could not be found. Make sure you have correct international codeset assembly installed and enabled.

How can I fix this problem?

[image: error message]